# How to get drop effect value in drag event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

There is a draggable element and droppable elements. Droppable elements set values to `event.dataTransfer.dropEffect` property on `dragover` event. By design the `dropEffect` value in the `drag` event listener of the dragged element should have the save value as the one set by `dragover` event listener. The problem is that the `dropEffect` value is always `none` in the `drag` event listener.

Is it possible to get the `dropEffect` value (which is set by `dragover` event listener) in `drag` event listener of dragged element?

Here is an example (the draggable element text should change to `copy` and `move` while dragging over the droppable elements):

```js
var draggable = document.getElementById( 'draggable' );
var draggableInfo = document.getElementById( 'draggable_info' );
var droppableCopy = document.getElementById( 'droppable-copy' );
var droppableMove = document.getElementById( 'droppable-move' );

draggable.addEventListener( 'dragstart', function( event ) {
  event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'all';
  event.dataTransfer.setData( 'text', 'Test' );
});

draggable.addEventListener( 'drag', function( event ) {
  draggableInfo.textContent = 'Drop effect: ' + event.dataTransfer.dropEffect;
});

draggable.addEventListener( 'dragend', function( event ) {
  draggableInfo.textContent = '';
});

droppableCopy.addEventListener( 'dragover', function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
});

droppableMove.addEventListener( 'dragover', function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
});
```

```css
#draggable,
#droppable-copy,
#droppable-move {
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 200px;
}
#draggable {
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<div id="draggable" draggable="true">
  Drag me!
  <div id="draggable_info"></div>
</div>

<div id="droppable-copy">
  Drop here to copy
</div>

<div id="droppable-move">
  Drop here to move
</div>
```

**Update.** I've found that browser console shows required `dropEffect` value if the `event.dataTransfer` object is inspected using `console.log(event.dataTransfer)`. But if you check this value using `setTimeout` after even a second it will still be `none`.

Comment: `event.target` is not the same at `dragover` and `drag` events

Comment: @guest271314 sure. But `dataTransfer` should be the same.